# passing data from controller to view advice required

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

i want to pass some data from my database on to a webpage i have Somme code in my model that specify what data i want to select and echo the data in my view my question is how would i go about passing Somme data in to view using the controller ? here is my code

survay/php

```
    <?php
class Survay extends CI_Model{

    function dosurvay($Question, $qA, $qB, $qC){
        $this->db->select('QID, Question, qA, qB, qC');
        $this->db->from('tblquestions');
        $this->db->where('Question', $Question);
        $this->db->where('qA', $qA);
        $this->db->where('qB', $qB);
        $this->db->where('qC', $qC);
         $this -> db -> limit(1);

   $query = $this -> db -> get();

   if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
   {
     return $query->result();
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
 }




}
?>
```

survay_view.php

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

    <h1><?php echo $Question;?></h1>
    <?php echo $qA; ?><?php form_checkbox('qA'); ?>
    <?php echo $qB; ?><?php form_checkbox('qB');?>
    <?php echo $qC; ?><?php form_checkbox('qC'); ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller

load your model

```
$this->load->model('survay');
```

call your model function

```
$survay_data = $this->survay->dosurvay($Question, $qA, $qB, $qC);
```

load your data to the view

```
$viewData = array();
$viewData['survay_data'] = $survay_data;
$this->load->view('survay_view', $viewData)
```

Comment: tnx for your help the code looks good saved me a lot of time i am sure this is a stupid question but i have uninitialized variables how do i initialize them?.